# How to get two output JSON Objects in js line chart?

Tags: javascript, json, charts

I would like to display two lines in a Chart.js line chart. The required data from the database I have a JSON file with 2 objects.

Now I want to display them in the line chart. If I only want to display one data set it is no problem. When displaying two lines at the same time I have no idea what to do. I tried to call the objects and then output them, but the output is always undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Error:**

```
Cannot read property 'current_week' of undefined
```

**JSON Output:**

```
{"current":[{"current_week":23},{"current_week":636},{"current_week":237}],"last":[{"last_week":235},{"last_week":74},{"last_week":737},{"last_week":767},{"last_week":546},{"last_week":73},{"last_week":453}]}
```

**JS Chart.js Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost/r6team-new/admin/includes/stats/website-weekly-stats.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      var current_week = [];
      var last_week = [];

      for(var i in data) {
        current_week.push(data.current[i].current_week);
        last_week.push(data.last[i].last_week);
      }

      console.log(current_week);
      console.log(last_week);

      var visitorsChart = {
        labels: ['MO', 'DI', 'MI', 'DO', 'FR', 'SA', 'SO'],
        datasets: [{
          type                : 'line',
          data                : current_week,
          backgroundColor     : 'transparent',
          borderColor         : '#007bff',
          pointBorderColor    : '#007bff',
          pointBackgroundColor: '#007bff',
          fill                : false
        },
        {
          type                : 'line',
          data                : last_week,
          backgroundColor     : 'tansparent',
          borderColor         : '#ced4da',
          pointBorderColor    : '#ced4da',
          pointBackgroundColor: '#ced4da',
          fill                : false
        }]
      };

      var ctx = $("#visitors-chart");

      var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        data: visitorsChart,
      });
    
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: could you please create a codepen for this  ?

Comment: are you sure that you are getting the data on this line 
current_week.push(data.current[i].current_week);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loop is incorrect

```
var current_week = [];
var last_week = [];

for(var i in data["current_week"]) {
   current_week.push(i["current_week"]);
}

for(var i in data["last_week"]) {
   last_week.push(i["last_week"]);
}
```

or make it more easier

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost/r6team-new/admin/includes/stats/website-weekly-stats.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data) {
      var visitorsChart = {
        labels: ['MO', 'DI', 'MI', 'DO', 'FR', 'SA', 'SO'],
        datasets: [{
          ...
          //current_week
          data: data["current"].map(d => d["current_week"])
        },
        {
         ...
          //last_week
          data: data["last"].map(d => d["last_week"]) 
        }]
      };

      var ctx = $("#visitors-chart");

      var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        data: visitorsChart
      });
    
    },
  });
});
```